# Rails site searching an awful lot of directories for files when starting up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, passenger, ruby-on-rails-plugins

We were experiencing some intermittent slowness of various Rails sites on our server -- Apache 2, Passenger, REE 1.8.7, various Rails versions (mostly 2.3.11). Had a fellow come in and look around to see if he could find what we could optimize. He came back with this excerpt from an strace he did of a Ruby process: http://pastebin.com/t9LD89dr

As you can see, an *awful lot* of paths, some of them quite nonsensical, are being searched for this same file. Even though it's actually being found on about the 8th attempt. Apparently this is happening for *many* .rb files being included by the app, resulting in a lot of wasteful disk activity.

Does anybody have an idea what's going on here and if we can do anything about it? I have a feeling this is what's slowing down the startup of our sites, which use a little in-house CMS we came up with. My first inclination is to blame Desert, which is used to allow us to develop plugin extensions to said CMS. But that's really no more than a guess. My other guess, after some fiddling around, is that this is that it's RubyGems. In any case, it makes restarting any app on our server r-e-e-e-a-a-a-l-l-l-l-l-y slow (and in the process, bogging down *every other app* on the server because of the way Passenger works) and something needs to be done about it.

Comment: Perhaps it's related to this? http://rhnh.net/2011/05/28/speeding-up-rails-startup-time and http://www.rubyinside.com/ruby-1-9-3-faster-loading-times-require-4927.html

Comment: It's possible. I've also begin to wonder if it's something RubyGems is up to. One thing that was pointed out to me is that a lot of the paths being searched are nonexistent and/or nonsensical, and appear to be concatenations of other paths.

Comment: Also, this isn't a real _solid_ observation, but the load time doesn't seem to be nearly as bad on my development environment, nor on a different server. Something about it suggests to me that it depends on how many system gems are installed on the environment it's running in -- this particular server has a lot, including multiple different versions of Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Install 'will_paginate'; as it appears this gem is missing.

Comment: no, its' installed. if it weren't, this site would error out and not start up at all, and I'd have gotten a very obvious error message to go with a very obvious error, and wouldn't be posting here.

Comment: Also this pastie is just an excerpt from the full strace. It's doing this for _every_ require.